# self.el vs this.el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm following a [backbone.js tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-2-crud/) and came across 2 functions `initialize()` and `render()`. `initialize()` used `$(self.el).append()` when appending some html while `render()` used `$(this.el).append()`. I am confused about the difference, would appreciate an explaination, thanks!

**JS Code**

```
// Views
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        var self = this;
        this.model.bind("add", function (wine) {
            $(self.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
        });
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
            $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW, you should not re-wrap the el with `$(this.el)`, use the cached el instead: `this.$el` or `self.$el`

Comment: `var self = this;` It's just a reference to the outer `this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first uses `self` to keep a reference to `this` when the scope changes when the event fires. Inside the anonymous function (for the event handler), `this` would refer to the element that fired the event rather than your Backbone controller.

The reference isn't needed in the second case.

Comment: How will the scope change when the event `add` fires? What will `this` refer to before and after the event is fired if `var self=this;` was not used?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is how JavaScript handles scope.

in the initialize function
they do

```
var self = this;
```

so when they bind the reference to the WineListView instance that initialized was called on

```
this.model.bind("add", function (wine) {
    $(self.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
 });
```

But it could be done without the self variable if you send "this" as the third parameter.
The third parameter should dictates scope that the callback should be called in

```
this.model.bind("add", function (wine) {
    $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
 }, this);
```

If you look at there render is bind, it also uses the third parameter

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
```

Disclamer i havnt tried the code, but got this from reading the docs on backbone
http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this